# Is there a way to add constructors using Groovy 2.0 Extensions

Tags: groovy, groovy-2

In the older (1.x.x) versions of Groovy you can add constructors using metaClass.constructor

```
Example.metaClass.constructor << { String arg0 -> new Example(arg0, "") }
```

Is there a way to register constructors using the new Groovy 2.0 extension modules?

**This seems to work:**

Define an extension class as normal for Groovy 2 and just add the constructors in a static initialiser

```
public class ExampleHelper {
    static {
        Example.metaClass.constructor << { String arg0 -> new Example(arg0, "") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of...

You could add a static factory method to the Example class ie:

```
class ExampleExtensionStatic {
  public static Example newInstance( Example type, String arg0 ) {
    new Example( arg0, '' )
  }
}
```

Then (after adding a link to this class in the `staticExtensionClasses` field of the `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` file), you could do:

```
Example.newInstance( 'arg0' )
```

This is something worth asking on the mailing list to see if constructors are worth adding to the Module Extension system.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I suspected as much but I was hoping for different. I'm trying to make a project I'm working on interoperable between Groovy 1.x and 2. Maybe I need to look at the "register your own" features but I don't see any documentation for that yet :-(

Comment: This is all I've found: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module

Comment: Yep, that was what I found. I was hoping to avoid the "Advanced Modules" bit as it is just check out these classes...

Comment: Ahhh yeah, I haven't dug in to the 'Advanced Modules' bit yet...  I guess it might be possible to write your own Module and registry classes -- but as I said, I haven't looked into that at all :-(